# Adjust image in a container maintaining the aspect ratio regardless of whether it is vertical or horizontal

Tags: css

I need help with what I mention in the title.

This is an example of what I want to achieve:

- [The same aspect ratio than the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA6Gm.jpg).
- [Vertical image on horizontal container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaK11.jpg).
- [The image is horizontal but is lower tall than the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPfpH.jpg).

If possible, I need the code only in css. But if you can not, how would it be in JavaScript or PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page. Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). Also while many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Hi @hellow, i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/8VJ38/1809/ the problem is that this is thinked only for fullscreen mode webs and i need for containers

Comment: Also I tried `max-width: 100%;height:auto` but the problem is the vertical images because in these case I need the opposite (`max-height: 100%;width:auto`)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, all what I need is included in a new css3 property named object-fit, thanks!